# Finding the annihilator of $(2-e^x)^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If we expand to $e^{2x}-4e^x+4$ we get that the annihilator for the first term is $(D-2)$, for the second term it is $(D-1)$ and for the third term it is just $D$. So the annihilator for the whole expression is $D(D-1)(D-2)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is right as checked.